# What are the default settings of ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT and ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I find there are two timeout options in netty: ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS means timeout value to setup a connection, and ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT means the request timeout. What are the default settings of these two options?

I didn't find the default values for these two parameters in Netty's official documentation (https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOption.html). Could you help me ?